# Elasticsearch - Implement Completion Suggestion in Java (API Version 5!)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to implement a **completion suggestion** for my java application. I've read the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) but could not find anything on how to implement it using the **Java API** in **Version 5.0.1**. (All i found was related to older versions)

```
this.client.prepareSuggest...
```

=> does not exist anymore

```
this.client.prepareSearch... .addSuggestion(csb);
```

=> does not accept CompletionSuggestionBuilder

This is my maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing it is like this:

```
CompletionSuggestionBuilder csb = SuggestBuilders.completionSuggestion("foo")
    .prefix("prefix");
client().prepareSearch()
    .suggest(new SuggestBuilder().addSuggestion("foo", csb))
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you also help me on how to specify **fuzziness** ? I cannot find a setter for that in **CompletionSuggestionBuilder**  => https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html#fuzzy

Comment: You can use the overloaded [`prefix(String, Fuzziness)` method](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7560101ec73331acb39a042bde6130e59e4bb630/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/suggest/completion/CompletionSuggestionBuilder.java#L150-L167) for that purpose

Comment: @Val Can't I access this as API? Like Sending a request with request body and getting the response instead writing one by one in java steps.

Comment: @Gibbs you can definitely use the [low level RETS client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-low-usage-requests.html) and send your DSL queries.

Comment: You really are an ES addict :) I am yet to try your another answer :) Soon will do it. Thanks man :) Does the performance differ with low level and high level client?

Comment: the high-level client uses the low-level client, so it should be quicker, but you won't really notice a thing.